# Why doesn't my PHP foreach work?

Tags: php

```
$start = true;
$new = "";
foreach($array as $val)
{
    if($start = true && $val != " ")
    {
        $start = false;
        $new .= strtoupper($val);
    }
    elseif($val == " ")
    {
        $new .= " ";
        $start = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $new .= strtolower($val);
    }
    $start = false;
}
```

Basically what happens is `$start` NEVER becomes `false` AND everything becomes capitalized. So it looks like the first `if` IS running, but for some reason NEVER SETS `$start` to `false`.

Comment: Here's stuff to read about [PHP comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you trying to do here? If its making the first letter of a string a uppercase, there is a function `ucwords` that accepts a string and capitalizes the first letter of each word. You could do a `ucwords(strtolower($string))` to perform the same transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot stress it enough: use the **yoda condition**

```
if(true == $var)
```

or generally:

```
if(CONSTANT == $VARIABLE)
```

and not

```
if($VARIABLE == CONSTANT) //which you'd wrongly type as "="
```

PHP would have told you what went wrong in that case - no matter how tired you are.

Looking for this bug (it happens to the best of the best too) is frustrating.

Let the tool (PHP) be supportive to you, don't make it work against you.

That was on a more general note. As for your problem, it's doable with a one-liner:

```
<?php
$array = "hEllo woRlD";

var_dump(ucwords(strtolower($array)));
```

Answer (score 1):

`$start = true` is an assignment, not a comparison. Use `==`.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! Spent like 1 hour on this. I am new to PHP so not used to that.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a single equals in your test, which means "assignment". You probably meant `==` (equality), but in this case, with booleans, you don't need to compare at all:

```
$start = true;
$new = "";
foreach($array as $val)
{
    if($start && $val != " ") // <-- remove the = true here
    {
        $start = false;
        $new .= strtoupper($val);
    }
    elseif($val == " ")
    {
        $new .= " ";
        $start = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $new .= strtolower($val);
    }
    $start = false;
}
```

Right now, it's getting interpreted as "Set `$start` to `true && $val != " "`" - definitely not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

`$start = true && $val != " "` means:

```
$start = (true && $val != " ")
$start = ($val != " ")
$start = !($val == " ") // $start is true except when $val is a single space.
```

I believe you meant `$start == true`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to upper case the first character of every word? If so, look into [`ucwords`](http://php.net/ucwords).