# php false place in condition

Tags: php

Usually comparing with `false` is done like this where `false` is on right side:

```
if(strpos($str, 'php') !== false) {
    // code
}
```

But I have also noticed at various places `false` on left side:

```
if(false !== strpos($str, 'php')) {
    // code
}
```

As far as I understand, they are same then why some people put `false` on left side? Is there anything special about it, something I am missing ?

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388861/why-doesnt-my-php-foreach-work/9388911#9388911 I can't see any reason particular to `!=`, except consistency with the **yoda condition**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats something inattentive developers invented

The "problem"

```
if ($var = false) { /* code */ }
```

The solution

```
if (false = $var) { /* code */ }
```

Latter one will fail and thus the developer sees, that he misses an additional `=`, `!`, ... here

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this article](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/what-are-yoda-conditions) for instance about **Yoda conditions**. The essence is that it can help you avoid typos, like forgetting one `=` in a comparison `==` causing accidental assignment of a variable instead of comparing it to the second value.

The Star Wars character, often times re-arranged the word sequence of sentences, hence its name.

In your specific example, Yoda syntax is useless since you can't "assign" a function. (I had to quote "assign" because the sentence doesn't even sound right, lol.)

A typo like this would break instantly:

```php
if (strpos($str, 'php') = true) { //...
```

So there's absolutely no reason to write it like this:

```php
if (true == strpos($str, 'php')) { //...
```

The Symfony framework style guidelines recommend or enforce the use of Yoda syntax, but not for pointless cases like this, and I believe this code would be rejected because it's horrible to read.

That's the main criticism of the technique, by the way. Cognitive load is increased when reading something like, "if red is apple" vs "if apple is red".