# if statement value position

Tags: php, optimization

What is the difference between the 2 statements:

```
if (false === $variable) {
  //do something
}
```

and

```
if ($variable === false) {
  //do something
}
```

I personally use the second style but often run into code in frameworks that i use which always seem to use the first style.

Is there a difference ( i suspect it is some legacy thing to do with types) or is this simply a coding habit (it must be rooted in something though??)

If not, what is the reasoning behind the first style given that the logic is actually backwards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do some experienced programmers write expressions this way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309089/why-do-some-experienced-programmers-write-expressions-this-way)

Comment: possible duplicate of [php false place in condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438043/php-false-place-in-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if ($foo = false)` (note: `=` instead of `==`) is a typical typo that leads to hard to debug problems. For that reason, some people prefer `false == $foo`, since the runtime will throw an error when you try to assign something to `false`.

Other than that there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the value that can't have something assigned to it (a literal, a constant, a function call, etc) on the left hand side then, if you accidentally use an assignment operator (`=`) instead of a comparison operator, then you'll get an error rather then a hard-to-track-down bug.

i.e.

```
if (false = $variable) { // Error
if ($variable = false) { // Valid code that doesn't do what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

This dates to C programming. It's a way to make sure "compilers" will fail if you accidently used = (assignment) and not == or === (equals) because "false" is not an lvalue (can't be on the left side of an assignment)

Answer (score 0):

It stems from this:

```
if (false = $variable)
```

syntax error

```
if ($variable = false)
```

accidental assignment

Answer (score 0):

It has been around for a while. It comes from accidentally writing (by forgetting one `=`):

```
if (c = 1) {
}
```

which does assignment and it's doesn't actually check whether `c` equals `1`. It assigns `1` and then it evaluates to 1 (so the if statement becomes always true due to that mistake). By writing

```
if (1 == c) {
}
```

as a habit, you cannot make that mistake. If you would forget the `=` in this case, the compiler would warn you because assignment to the literal `1` is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, **the two statements are equivalent**.

So, ***why to write it this way or the other (?)*** :

- Try to avoid a *typical typo* : `if ($condition = false)` instead of `if ($condition == false)`. In that case, your 2nd version would cause a difficult-to-debug issue, while the first would throw an error
- Want to force one of the two parts of the conditional statement be **evaluated first** (the rightmost)