# Order in conditional statements

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php false place in condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438043/php-false-place-in-condition)

I have noticed that a lot of PHP code uses conditional statements like CONST == VARIABLE. I grew up with the syntax always articulated in reverse. Is there a reason for this structure?

Example:

```
 // this is the way I see it most typically represented in PHP
 if ( false == $foobar ) { // do this }

 // this is the way I normally do it
 if ( $foobar == false ) { // do this }
```

Comment: It's often called a "Yoda condition". Some people use it to prevent assignment typos in place of equality. My opinion is not to introduce typos, rather than an odd coding convention to guard against them.

Comment: it is better: if(!$foobar) { // do this }

Comment: but both has same result

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is to prevent a common typo between `==` and `=`, known as a yoda condition. Consider the following:

```
if( false = $foobar) {
```

This would result in an error, catching what would be considered a bug, since you cannot assign anything to `false`. On the contrary:

```
if( $foobar = false) {
```

This is valid syntax, and is quite an easy mistake to make.

However, I typically prefer the `if( $foobar == false)` syntax, as unit tests should be able to catch these programmatic mistakes.

Comment: I wonder why someone would like to explicitly test `$foobar == false`, when simple `! $foobar` should have sufficed. ) Of course, `$foobar === false` is completely another story. )

Comment: @raina77ow In PHP and some other dynamically typed langs, boolean `FALSE` is a separate specific thing from "falsiness".  Consider `$var = ""`;.  `!$var` is true, but sometimes you need to verify that it is actually boolean `FALSE`.

Comment: With PHP, it helps for functions that return both `0` and `false`, e.g. `strpos()`. So, `$foobar = strpos( $haystack, $needle);` can have a valid return value of `0`, or `false` on error.

Comment: Are you both implying that this kind of test is possible with `==`? ) But that's the form used in the original question, hence my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The way you normally do it is exactly how most programmers do it. The first example is called a yoda condition:

http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html

and is not the norm.